# calling an iframe whilst clicking on one or more checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to call different iframe once i click on one or more checkbox.
The idea is about getting different charts into one graph.
I tried this into my html file :

```js
function control(){
  var checkedValue = null; 
  var inputElements = document.getElementsByName('check_list[]');
  for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
      if(inputElements[i].checked){
           checkedValue = inputElements[i].value;
           break;
                                  }
          return checkedValue;
                                     }
  if checkedValue == 'TotalVoiceTrafficBH2'
  { <iframe src="http://localhost/xampp/www/interactive_php_mysql_charts/chart_trans2.html" width="700" height="500"/> }
  }
        if checkedValue == 'TotalVoiceTrafficBH1'
{ <iframe src="http://localhost/xampp/www/interactive_php_mysql_charts/chart_trans1.html" width="700" height="500"/> }
  }
```

any help please ?
I need to superpose these iframes whilst my user click on 2 or more checkoboxes !

Answer (score 0):

Bellow an example

```
function checkValue() {
  var checkedValue = null;
  var inputElements = document.getElementsByName('check_list[]');
  for (var i = 0; inputElements[i]; ++i) {
    if (inputElements[i].checked) {
      checkedValue = inputElements[i].value;
      break;
    }
    return checkedValue;
  }
}


var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');


switch(checkValue()) {
    case 'TotalVoiceTrafficBH2':
       iframe.src = 'http://localhost/xampp/www/interactive_php_mysql_charts/chart_trans2.html';
        break;
    case 'TotalVoiceTrafficBH1':
       default:
        iframe.src = 'http://localhost/xampp/www/interactive_php_mysql_charts/chart_trans1.html';
        break;

}
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me, i should mention that my checkboxes are into <form name="form1" method="post" action="transfert.php" target="_blank"> . I mean that their values are posted to another php file. so still appropriate getting their values into the html file ?

Comment: well, i put my javascript code into the html body, and i get only the second iframe, mean the default one, any other suggestions @Vladu ?!